# WebStorm typings.d.ts types are red

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

Currently, I'm using WebStorm 2021.2.3 Mac version.

I added a `typings.d.ts` containing a few generic Angular form types. I started using them, everything was cool. And now my IDE is just simply turning these types into red, but still finding them. What did I accidentally change maybe, or what's going on?

It even tells me that it's coming from `src/typings.d.ts`, but then why is it red?

[image]

P.S. I'm not using 'any' obviously in the generic formarray :)

Comment: have you add following configuration on your `tsconfig.json` ? `"types": ["node", "velocity-animate"]` and  `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`. Of course types have to be adjusted based on your context.

Comment: typeRoots is there, others not, but this typings.d.ts in the src folder should work by default, isnt it? at least it worked a few hours ago.

Comment: yes, it should you are right, maybe add it on `typeRoots`

Comment: I did, didn't work, still red, but can navigate to it.

Comment: have you try to remove the `.idea` folder ? maybe you have corrupted the internal cache

Comment: as far as I can see from screenshot, the IDE itself does see the type but the built-in tsc compiler doesn't. Must be a Typescript misconfiguration - required typings aren't included in `tsconfig.json` used for current `.ts` file processing

Comment: I added my typings.d.ts path to the typeRoots array, still nothing. The fun part is that sometimes (for me it seems like totally random) it's not red.